# SwiftUI : How I can do .onDelete to Grouped Item?

Tags: listview, swiftui

structure of Item with children,

```
import Foundation

struct Item : Identifiable {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var group : String? = nil
    var children : [Children] = []
}

struct Children : Identifiable  {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var word : String? = nil
    var meaning : String? = nil
}
```

This is Models,

```
import Foundation

class ItemModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items : [Item] = []
   
    func addNewFolder(text : String) {
        
        let newFolder = Item(group : text)
        items.append(newFolder)
        print(items)
    }
    
    func addNewChildren(item : Item, word : String, meaning : String) {
        
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
            let newChildren = Children(word : word, meaning : meaning)
            items[index].children.append(newChildren)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteItem(indexSet : IndexSet) {
        items.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
    
    func moveItem(from :IndexSet, to : Int) {
        items.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
    }
    
}
```

This is first folderView

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddChildrenView: View {
    
    @State var word : String = ""
    @State var meaning : String = ""
    @State var isShowAlert : Bool = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var itemModel : ItemModel
    
    var item : Item
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(item.children) { item in
                WordListRowView(children: item)
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                   
                }
            }
        .navigationTitle("words")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
              Button(action: {
                addChildren()
              }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
              }))
        }
    }
}

extension AddChildrenView {
    func addChildren() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saving word", message: "Type word and meaning ", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        alert.addTextField { word in
            word.placeholder = "Type a word"
        }
        
        alert.addTextField { meaning in
            meaning.placeholder = "a meaning of word"
        }
        
        let addfolderAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: {
            (_) in
            self.word = alert.textFields![0].text!
            self.meaning = alert.textFields![1].text!
            itemModel.addNewChildren(item: item, word: word, meaning: meaning)
            print(itemModel.items)
        })
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {
            (_) in
        })
        alert.addAction(addfolderAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

What I want to do is like 'Notes'

**first view will display folder only,
and by clicking navigationLink.**

I want to show Children List.
But I don't know how I can do .onDelete to children list.

I can't find specific way that I can delete that with swiping motions or others.

Help me please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `deleteItem` and `moveItem` funcs need IndexSets – that is something you would use with `.onMove` and `.onDelete` directly on the `ForEach`.

If you want to stay with `.swipeActions` you have to do it differently. I did a complete demo for you here:

```
struct Item : Identifiable {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var group : String? = nil
    var children : [Children] = []
}

struct Children : Identifiable  {
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var word : String? = nil
    var meaning : String? = nil
}


class ItemModel : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items : [Item] = []
    
    func addNewFolder(text : String) {
        
        let newFolder = Item(group : text)
        items.append(newFolder)
        print(items)
    }
    
    func addNewChildren(item : Item, word : String, meaning : String) {
        
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
            let newChildren = Children(word : word, meaning : meaning)
            items[index].children.append(newChildren)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteItem(_ item: Item) {
        items.removeAll(where: {$0.id == item.id})
    }

    func deleteChildren(_ child: Children, in item: Item) {
        if let index = items.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == item.id}) {
            items[index].children.removeAll(where: {$0.id == child.id})
        }
    }
}


struct AddChildrenView: View {
    
    @State var word : String = ""
    @State var meaning : String = ""
    @State var isShowAlert : Bool = false
    
    @State private var nr = 1

    @EnvironmentObject var itemModel : ItemModel
    
    var item : Item
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(item.children) { child in
                HStack {
                    Text(child.word ?? "")
                    Text(child.meaning ?? "no meaning")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                //                WordListRowView(children: item)
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                        itemModel.deleteChildren(child, in: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("words")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                Button(action: {
            itemModel.addNewChildren(item: item, word: "Test word \(nr)", meaning: "Test meaning \(nr)")
            nr += 1
            //                addChildren()
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }))
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var itemModel = ItemModel()
    
    @State private var nr = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(itemModel.items) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    AddChildrenView(item: item)
                } label: {
                Text(item.group ?? "")
                }
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                    Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
                            itemModel.deleteItem(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("words")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                Button(action: {
            itemModel.addNewFolder(text: "Test group \(nr)")
            nr += 1
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }))
        }
        .environmentObject(itemModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly solved! Thank you so much Chris!! I have living with this problem for 2weeks..